# How to compare username entered by the user to the password stored in the file?

Tags: python-2.7, file

I am trying to make a bank which stores the username and password entered by the user in a file (text file).Now when , the user logs in he enters his username.Now how do i compare whether this username entered by the user is the same as the stored password when he/she created the account (stored in passw.txt).
Here is my code,

```
store_user=open("user.txt","a")
store_passw=open("passw.txt","a")
print "Type 1 to create a new acc or 2 to log in"
a=input("Your choice: ")
if a==1:

    a=raw_input("Enter your username: ")
    store_user.write(a+'\n')
    store_user.close()

    b=raw_input("Enter pass: ")
    store_passw.write(b+'\n')
    store_passw.close()
elif a==2:
    a=raw_input("Enter username: ")
    '''

    Now how do I comapare the username entered by the user with my file user.txt
    And also it should check the same userame has same associated password with passw.txt

    '''
```

I would also like to know is this method easier or shall i store username and password in a dictionary and then append it in a file.If i do so , then how would i get the the username and password out of it? (Like a user enters his username , now how does my program go to the file where is username and password is stored and check if the username (key) matches to the password (value).

Answer (score 0):

You need a structure. For instance you can use row number to get pair - user-password. That brings more problems then you can expect. Please use structure, and keep your data consistent. For instance you can put them into single file - reading whole record - name, password - goes always as single pice. There are simple ways - like comma separated values - python has csv module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html . Or you can go for something more complicated - JSON, XML - here is link for json: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not store in 2 files, but use a delimiter between elements and an other delimiter between values for that element

Example "Test1,pass1\nTest2,pass2" would be delimiter "\n" and ","

for your code you will have to find the linecount in file 1 then skip to that line in the other file to compare the passwords:

psudocode

```
open username
linefound = -1
for line,lineid in file
   if line == user
       linefound = lineid
close username
if linefound >= 0
   open password
   for line, lineid in file
        if lineid == linefound
           //compare do rest
```